# Interpreting the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test results to test if our data follows a Gamma distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov

Getting the result from the KS test:

`from scipy import stats
stats.kstest(myarray, 'gamma', (a, b))`

we conclude that `myarray` does not follow a gamma distribution in case `p<0.01` (when rejecting the null hypothesis)?

In addition, when we calculate the `a` and `b` of the gamma distribution (used for comparing our data) from our data, we cannot use the KS test results?

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: two questions: 1. rejecting the null hypothesis (by examining the p-value) means that myarray does not follow a gamma distribution?   2. when we calculate the a and b of the gamma distribution from our data, is the KS test meaningless (as i have read in some posts? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes - that's what the p value indicates - the probability of observing a KS statistic as extreme as this if my_array follows the gamma distribution is less than 1 percent.
2. I wouldn't say that it is meaningless, in the sense that deriving parameters and then doing a KS test on the same data is not the same as a tautology like 1 =1, but it is of not much value practically. It is best to use a different array for testing, and in case an array is not available - then you can do a parameter estimation on, say, 50 percent of the data and the KS test on the other 50 percent.

Also, this question is better suited for the stats.stackexchange.com forum